# Sprite-Kit - How to make a text heavy popup menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

At the end of the WWDC video (Session 503, Designing with Sprite-Kit) the speaker mentions that we can "Use standard UIKit controls as subviews of SKView". I thought this would be great for creating a popup mid game that has a paragraph of help text with some UIButtons and whatnot but I can't get this to work at all.

In my scene's init, I try something simple, like:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:v];
```

But nothing appears.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

If not, how do you create text-heavy popup menus mid-game using sprite-kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue. What you need to do is call the

```
-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {}
```

method. This is when the SKView is about to be added on top of the UIView I believe. You can place your code in there and it'll show up on your scene.

A warning: I am not sure if it only appears as the view is loading or not, but that is how I went about it

hope it helps

Comment: Weird, I added my code to the "- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view" area of the scene and still no blue UIView appears. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Where are you initializing/creating the UIView? Try doing it all in that method, and then adding the UIView with [self.view addSubview:view];

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible because SKView is a derived class of UIView.
All you need to do is, move the above code to -(void) viewDidLoad (in the ViewController.m file).

So it should look like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v];
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, which applies it to the main view controller but not the scene so it's still not visible. I also tried adding my view to the skview I create in the viewDidLoad before calling presentScene, but no dough.